# ASP.NET Core what could trigger 404 after ajax call?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, exception

Here is what's in my `Startup.cs`.

**Question**: not sure if it's duplicated to have both `UseExceptionHandler` and `UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects`?

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        //app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/Error");
        //app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Error/StatusCode/{0}");

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

And here is my `ErrorController`. My impression is for all the status code between 400-599 it should all goes to `StatusCode` action, correct?

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();            
    }

    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        //var exception = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();

        //var statusCode = HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;
        //var message = exception.Error.Message;
        //var stackTrace = exception.Error.StackTrace;

        //return View();
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult StatusCode(int? Id)
    {
        if (Id.HasValue && Id != null)
        {
            if (Id == 404 || Id == 500 || Id == 403)
            {
                var viewName = Id.ToString();
                //return View("StatusCode");

                return View("StatusCode", new ErrorViewModel { ErrorCode = Id.ToString() });
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

Then I have simple page with a button which triggers a HTTPPost ajax call pass some data to the backend method `SendEmails` to do some work. Then show the successful dialog I embedded on the page.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("SendEmails")',
    data: emails,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (response) {
        if (response) {
            $("#successfulDialog").dialog("open");
        }
        else {
            $("#failedDialog").dialog("open");
        }
    },
    error: function (request) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
});
```

Everything works as expected for this `SendEmails` Ajax call so far. But for some reason, I couldn't figure out that causes when the successful dialog shows, the `StatusCode` action in `ErrorController` was invoked few times with a 404 error.

I am wondering is there any way, I could find out where the request is coming from to trigger that 404 error or use the `UseDeveloperExceptionPage` or similar to display all the info?

I tried to remove the line

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Error/StatusCode/{0}");
```

from `Startup.cs`, obviously it stops sending the errors to the `StatusCode` action in `ErrorController`, but it doesn't go to any page, I even tried the `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error")` in the home controller, it doesn't go there either.

So I am wondering if anyone could enlighten me where I should go or check to figure out what triggers the 404 error after the popup dialog shows on the page.

Thank you.

Comment: No, It's not duplicated to have both `EseExceptionHandler` and `UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects`, `UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects` will handle non-successful status code responses and   `EseExceptionHandler` will catch unhandled exceptions in your application. From your description, I also can't figure out why `UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects` be triggered, When you remove `UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects` and use `UseDeveloperExceptionPage`, Does it show any useful information?

Comment: May be you can try to use [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to catch some error.